# Difference between large numpy arrays containing time values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time, python-datetime

I have ten (1000,1000) numpy arrays. Each array element contains a float, which represents the hour of the day. E.g. 14.0 = 2pm and 15.75 = 15:45pm.

I want to find the maximum difference between these arrays. The result should be a single (1000,1000) numpy array containing, for each array element, the maximum difference between the ten arrays . At the moment I have the following, which seems to work fine:

```
import numpy as np

max=np.maximum.reduce([data1,data2,data3,data4,data5]) 
min=np.minimum.reduce([data1,data2,data3,data4,data5])

diff=max-min
```

However, it results in the difference between 11pm and 1am of 22 hours. I need the difference to be 2 hours. I imagine I need to use datetime.time somehow, but I don't know how to get datetime to play nicely with numpy arrays.

---

Edit: The times refer to the average time of day that a certain event occurs, so they are not associated with a specific date. The difference two times could therefore be correctly interpreted as 22 hours, or 2 hours. However, I will always want to take the minimum of those two possible interpretations.

Comment: Without the date, how do you know the time difference between 11pm and 1am is 2 hours and not 22 hours. You need the date to resolve the ambiguity. If it's the same day, its 22 hours; if they're from consecutive days, its 2 hours.

Comment: Do you want like the minimum distance, since you don't have days? Like your example states, it could be 22 hours or 2 hours...

Comment: The times aren't associated with a date, they just refer to the average time of day that a certain event occurs. So the difference could be interpreted as 22 hours, or 2 hours, but I will always want to take the minimum of those two possible interpretations.

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum element-wise comparison difference or maximum difference between all possible pairs of arrays 1 and 2?

Comment: I am looking for the maximum element-wise comparison difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the difference between two cyclic values by centering one value around the center location in the cycle (12.0). Rotate the other values the same amount to maintain their relative differences. Take the modulus of the adjusted values by the duration of the cycle to keep everything within bounds. You now have times adjusted so the maximum maximum possible distance stays within +/- 1/2*cycle duration (+/-12 hours).

e.g.,

```
adjustment = arr1 - 12.0
arr2 = (arr2 - adjustment) % 24.0
diff = 12.0 - arr2 # or abs(12.0 - arr2) if you prefer
```

If you're not using the absolute value, you'll need to play with the sign depending on which time you want to be considered 'first'.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the number 11pm and 1am, and you want to find the minimum distance.

```
1am -> 1
11pm -> 23
```

Then you have either:

```
23 - 1 = 22
```

Or,

```
24 - (23 - 1) % 24 = 2
```

Then distance can be thought of as:

```
def dist(x,y):
    return min(abs(x - y), 24 - abs(x - y) % 24)
```

Now we need to take `dist` and apply it to every combination, If I recall correctly, there is a more `numpy/scipy` oriented function to do this, but the concept is more or less the same:

```
from itertools import combinations

data = [data1,data2,data3,data4,data5]
combs = combinations(data,2)
comb_list = list(combs)
dists = [dist(x,y) for x,y in comb_list]
max_dist = max(dists)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array `diff` of the time differences ranging between 0 and 24 hours you can make a correction to the wrongly calculated values as follows:

```
diff[diff > 12] = 24. - diff[diff > 12]
```